# Adding and combining data in React componentDidUpdate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a functional component that compiles data (this.state.scanlist) in an object in this format:

```
0:
brand: "AATEST"
exp: "2022-08-25"
gtin: "15735423000247"
iname: "Arthur's Test Item"
lot: "EEEFFF"
qty: 5
ref: "TESTREFE"

1:
brand: "AATEST"
exp: "2022-08-25"
gtin: "15735423000247"
iname: "Arthur's Test Item"
lot: "CCCDDD"
qty: 3
ref: "TESTREFE"

2:
brand: "AATEST"
exp: "2022-08-25"
gtin: "15735423000247"
iname: "Arthur's Test Item"
lot: "CCCDDD"
qty: 2
ref: "OTHERTESTREF"
```

I would like to have a new object with the following expected output every time the component updates:

```
0:
ref: "TESTREFE"
qty: 8

1:
ref: "OTHERTESTREF"
qty: 2
```

Also if there is a more practical way of doing this in react I would love to hear about it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using `Array.reduce`, it's not related to `react` :

```js
const obj = [{
    brand: "AATEST",
    exp: "2022-08-25",
    gtin: "15735423000247",
    iname: "Arthur's Test Item",
    lot: "EEEFFF",
    qty: 5,
    ref: "TESTREFE"
  },

  {
    brand: "AATEST",
    exp: "2022-08-25",
    gtin: "15735423000247",
    iname: "Arthur's Test Item",
    lot: "CCCDDD",
    qty: 3,
    ref: "TESTREFE"
  },
  {
    brand: "AATEST",
    exp: "2022-08-25",
    gtin: "15735423000247",
    iname: "Arthur's Test Item",
    lot: "CCCDDD",
    qty: 2,
    ref: "OTHERTESTREF"
  }
]

const result = obj.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  // check if an object with the current ref value exists in the accumulator
  const ndx = acc.findIndex(e => e.ref === curr.ref)
  if (ndx > -1) {
    // if it exists, increment the qty
    acc[ndx].qty += 1
  } else {
    // if it does not exist, push a new object to the accumulator
    acc.push({
      ref: curr.ref,
      qty: curr.qty
    })
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I believe this may be correct! I had something similar to this but I am still having inconsistent results (counts) . It may be my usage of the state causing this. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Interestingly enough. When I run this on the following data I get qty: 5. It seems to count the first listing and than only count one for each additional listing: [{"brand":"AATEST","ref":"TESTREFE","iname":"Arthur's Test Item","gtin":"15735423000247","exp":"2022-08-25","lot":"AAABBB","qty":3},{"brand":"AATEST","ref":"TESTREFE","iname":"Arthur's Test Item","gtin":"15735423000247","exp":"2022-08-25","lot":"CCCDDD","qty":3},{"brand":"AATEST","ref":"TESTREFE","iname":"Arthur's Test Item","gtin":"15735423000247","exp":"2022-08-25","lot":"EEEFFF","qty":3}]